# How to calculate the time difference between two columns on multiple rows in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have this PHP Code:

```
    $sql="SELECT ticket_seq, SUM(TIMEDIFF(timeend, timestart)) as total FROM ticket_updates GROUP BY ticket_seq";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $sql2="SELECT * from tickets where ticketnumber = '".$result["ticket_seq"]."' ";
        $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);

        $sql3="SELECT * from customer where sequence = '".$result2["company"]."' ";
        $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3);

        if($result["total"] > $result3["support_hours"])
        {
            echo $result3["company"].' - '.$result["total"].'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

but then when i echo $result["total"] i just get random numbers.

I am trying to select the time difference between timestart and timeend for multiple rows and add it together.

Comment: Are those fields date / time fields, or are they maybe unix timestamps?

Comment: they are DATETIME fields

Comment: Not sure that you can usefully sum up a date / time, which is the result of TIMEDIFF. Probably best to convert to unix timestamps, subtract one from the other and sum the resulting seconds.

Comment: As an aside, looking at that code you can probably do it using a single SELECT, joining to the other tables, rather than one select and looping round the results and doing 2 for each result. The single select would likely be far quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will solve your issue

```
SELECT SUM(
   (SELECT TIMEDIFF(timeend, timestart) FROM ticket_updates GROUP BY ticket_seq)
)
```

Comment: When i try this code i get the error:

Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0):

Quick play and something like this might do it:-

```
$sql="SELECT ticket_updates.ticket_seq, customer.company, SUM(CAST((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timeend) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestart)) AS UNSIGNED)) as total 
    FROM ticket_updates 
    INNER JOIN tickets ON tickets.ticketnumber = ticket_updates.ticket_seq
    INNER JOIN customer ON customer.sequence = tickets.company
    GROUP BY ticket_updates.ticket_seq, customer.company
    HAVING total > (customer.support_hours*60*60)";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
            echo $result3["company"].' - '.$result["total"].'<br>';
    }
}
```

This is converting the date/time fields to unix timestamps, finding the diffence and casting it to unsigned and then checking that against the support hours multiplied by 60 and 60 (ie, converting from hours to seconds)